# How to unpack a nested list in python to sublists?

Tags: python, list

Assume that my list is:

```
[ [1,2,3,4], [ [[5], [6]], [7] ]]
```

After unpack, I want to get `[1,2,3,4], [5], [6], [7]`

How to do it with low time complexity?

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Comment: `[s for sub in L for s in sub]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: What is the expected outcome of unpacking [ [ 1, 2 ], 3 ] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) flattens an iterable completely. You just need a slight tweak to make the process stop one step earlier:

```
import collections
def flattish(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
            if any(isinstance(e, collections.Iterable) for e in el):
                for sub in flattish(el):
                    yield sub
            else:
                    yield el
        else:
            yield [el]
```

The `any(...` will check if that iterable contains any iterables. This will flatten something like `[1, [2, 3]]`, but leave `[5]` as-is. Additionally, the `yield [el]` ensures that any non-iterables will be contained in a `list`, so your result will be a `list` that contains only `list`s, some of which may have only a single element.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Don't use the regex hacks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [[[5], [6]], [7]]]
>>> eval(re.sub(r'([][])\1+', '\\1', str(x)))
([1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7])
```

@TigerhawkT3's answer is faster for this `x`, 28.9 µs per loop vs 41.8 µs per loop

so just for fun

```
import json
json.loads(re.sub(r'([][])\1+', '\\1', str(x)))
```

puts the regex back to 22.1 µs per loop

Comment: Should I explain the regex or do people prefer to work it out themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `re`.

```
import re
x=[ [1,2,3,4], [ [[5], [6]], [7] ]]
print map(lambda x:map(int,re.findall(r"\d+(?=.*\])",x)),re.findall(r"\[[^\[\]]*\]",str(x)))
```

Output:`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]`

Comment: Nice idea, but what is the time complexity

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
>>> final_list = []
>>> def make_single(input_list):
    final_list_inside = []
    for i in input_list:
        if any(isinstance(el, list) for el in input_list):
            make_single(i)
        else:
            final_list_inside.append(i)
    if(len(final_list_inside) != 0):
        final_list.append(final_list_inside)


>>> make_single([[1, 2, 3, 4], [[[5], [6]], [7]]])
>>> final_list
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just recursively check for good lists : good lists are those which don't contain lists. Each list is visited one time only.

```
def prettyflat(ll):
    pf=[]
    def good(ll):
        isgood = isinstance(ll,list) and  all([not good(l) for l in ll])
        if isgood : u.append(ll)
        return isgood
    good(ll)
    return pf
```

Output:`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]`